# Get emails from html source

Tags: c#, parsing, email, html-agility-pack

i have a html source, where is a few emails. I need grab this emails but i doesnt known how.

It is posible with HtmlagilityPack?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: what have tried already?

Comment: I try use HtmlAgilityPack. I can parse Table, Link or Img, etc. But i dont know how parse emails...

Comment: @Horak Jakub, I think it would be simplier to find emails by using regex

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible but you must be sure that all (current and future) the HTML must be in same format, in case you are going to need the same code.

But before that , can you show us via some code, what you have tried / what you want to achieve?
That would be a great help to community and you too....

Comment: There will be a problem. Html page will look different goes wrong. So emails will be written differently:

- As a reference in <a> tag (mailto: email@email.cz)
- As text only

I think it will be even more options. Therefore, I needed something versatile. In HtmlAgilityPack only came here on how to search for text inside the tag, and not how to retrieve emails.